# Issues with windows Update

Tags: windows-10, updates

I have a proxy internet in my university.
I have used the proxy in my proxy settings as 172.30.10.10 and port 3128. Now, Windows Update is not working, showing error 0x8024401c. I have searched and tried many solutions, including importing the proxy using `winhttp` in cmd and putting proxy in network isolation in gpedit. 
Every time, I made change, I restarted my laptop but still it comes with the same error. I have installed Windows 10 1709. 
Note: I updated all the updates using my home internet which is free proxy net. There everything was fine. But here, showing problem. Help me with that.
Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which solutions you already tried, or risk getting the same solutions again.

Comment: Sounds like the proxy is configured in such a way, that you won’t be able to update Windows, while connected to it.

Comment: You can download the updates from the Microsoft site. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-download-and-install-windows-10-cumulative-updates-manually

Comment: The proxy is not configured for all the apps and updates. Likewise, store is not working.

Comment: In my solutions, I tried importing proxy, sfc scan, network isolation and set the value to 0 in windows update in locak key machine in the regedit.

Comment: 0x8024401c = timeout. manually download the MSU from [update catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)